# Assembly PE64 Console Can't Find Command-line Arguments Count and Array (argc) + (argv)

Tags: assembly, x86-64, fasm

im working on an Assembly project for Win64 and i have a problem with Command-line Argument !!!! in a normal situation, the address of Command-line Argument is:

```
[rsp] = Number of Command-line Arguments
[rsp+8] = First Argument (Name of Executable)
[rsp+16] = First Client Argument
....
```

but in in my situation, these are not the Values that i want ! (**[rsp] is not the number of ... and [rsp+8] is not argument and ....**)

this is my source code (**FASM PE64 CONSOLE**)

```
FORMAT  PE64 CONSOLE
ENTRY   MAIN

SECTION '.text' CODE READABLE EXECUTABLE
MAIN:
        mov     r12, [rsp] ; now r12 is the number of Commandline Arguments (but it's not !!!!!!!!!!!!)
        sub     rsp, 56

        mov     ecx, -11
        call    [K32.GetStdHandle]

        cmp     r12, 1  ; Argument Count Must be More than 1 (because it's 1 by default (Executable name) and we want to print, if it's More than 1 (if Argument Provided))
        jle     .exit

        .write:
                mov     ecx, eax                ; STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE (EAX)
                mov     rdx, .hello
                mov     r8d, .hello_len
                xor     r9d, r9d
                mov     QWORD [rsp+32], 0
                call    [K32.WriteFile]

        .exit:
                add     rsp, 56

                xor     ecx, ecx
                call    [K32.ExitProcess]

                hlt

        .hello  DB 'Argument Received', 0x00
        .hello_len = $ - .hello

SECTION '.idata' IMPORT DATA READABLE WRITABLE
DD      0,0,0,RVA K32DLL,RVA K32
DD      0,0,0,0,0


K32DLL DB 'KERNEL32.DLL', 0x00

K32:
        .ExitProcess            DQ RVA ___ExitProcess
        .GetStdHandle           DQ RVA ___GetStdHandle
        .WriteFile              DQ RVA ___WriteFile
                                DQ 0

___ExitProcess          DB 0,0,'ExitProcess',0
___GetStdHandle         DB 0,0,'GetStdHandle',0
___WriteFile            DB 0,0,'WriteFile',0
```

in My Program, if we add an argument, it's Must print the Message. otherwise it's Must just EXIT but it Always print that Message (The value of 'Number of Command-line Arguments' is wrong !)

Also i check the 'rcx' as the number of Command-line Arguments and 'rdx' as Arguments Array but still they aren't !!!

Where is the argc and argv !!!!!!!!!! is this about my Format ? (PE64 Console) ?

Comment: See the [microsoft documentation about the entry point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/winmain--the-application-entry-point) and [CommandLineToArgvW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-commandlinetoargvw)

Comment: i read about it ... a little useful ... but a question !!! i have to change the entry name to 'WinMain' or with this name, i still have the parameters too ?

Comment: The name shouldn't matter. In any case you could also call [GetCommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinew)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command-line arguments, including the name of executable itself, are parsed by OS and put on stack in [Linux](https://euroassembler.eu/maclib/linabi.htm#GetArg)
but things are very different in Windows. You need to invoke kernel function [GetCommandLineA()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processenv/nf-processenv-getcommandlinea) and parse the returned string by yourself.

Invoking ExitProcess never returns to the exited program, so your instruction **hlt** will not execute and should be omitted.